# Dompdf output contains weird borders

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I'm currently trying to convert a HTML file into PDF file using DOMPDF. However the converted pdf files contains these red and yellow borders. Is there any way to remove these borders?

[image]

Part of my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('styles/CPP.css')?>" type="text/css" />-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <!--<img src="<?php echo base_url('styles/logo.gif')?>"/>-->
        </div>
        <div id="version-date">
            <p>Version date: 26 Aug 2015</p>
        </div>
        <div id="form-title">
            <p><i>Research and Consultancy Office</i></p>
            <p>Graduate Studies and Research Education</p>
            <p style="font-size: 25px"><strong>Conference Participation Proposal</strong></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="info">
        <p>This form will be used by Coordinating Supervisors to recommend their research students for
            conference participation. File Naming Instruction for 2015. For an applicant associated with the
            FECS Faculty, intending to participate in the conference CONF2015, please save the form with a
            file name like this: <strong>2015</strong> FECS <strong>Student Name (</strong>CONF2015 <strong>
                Participation Proposal).docx</strong></p>
    </div>


    <div id="form-content">
        <!--<table border="1">-->
        <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th class="table-title" colspan="4">STUDENT DETAILS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-right">Student ID</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="align-right-a">Student Name</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-right">Course (MBus/MSc/PhD)</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="align-right-a">Date of Enrolment</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-right">Research Focus or Topic</td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="align-right">Coordinating Supervisor</td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

My controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $data = "123";
        $html = $this->load->view('CPP_form/Conference_Participation_Proposal.html',$data,true);
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream('CPP_Form.pdf',array('Attachment'=>0));
        //$this->load->view('CPP_form/Conference_Participation_Proposal.html');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have put DOMPDF_DEBUG_LAYOUT constants to true in dompdf.config.php